# redux-toolkit action not triggered in reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to trigger a simple action using @reduxjs/Toolkit but it's not working.

I see that the action is dispatched but it's like the slice reducer is not listening to it or something.

```
const say = createAction("ui/say", what => ({ payload: what }));

const uiSlice = createSlice({
  name: "ui",
  initialState: { said: "" },
  reducers: {
    [say.type]: (state, action) => {
      console.log("saying", action.payload); //<-- not showing, why?
      state.currentList = action.payload;
    }
  }
});

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: combineReducers({
    ui: uiSlice.reducer
  })
});

const Chat = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [whatToSay, setWhatToSay] = useState("");
  const whatWasSaid = useSelector(state => state.ui.said);

  const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(say(whatToSay));
    setWhatToSay("");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <input type="text" onChange={e => setWhatToSay(e.target.value)} />
        <button>Say</button>
      </form>
      {whatWasSaid ? <p>You said: {whatWasSaid}</p> : <p>Say something</p>}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here's a minimal reproducing example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-toolkit-0tzxs?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you mismatched the [`createSlice` API](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createslice).

From your code, you trying to implement a listener for an action, so you might want to use `extraReducers` instead:

```
const uiSlice = createSlice({
  name: "ui",
  initialState: { said: "" },
  // Not reducers: {}
  extraReducers: {
    [say.type]: (state, action) => {
      console.log("saying", action.payload);
      state.currentList = action.payload;
    }
  }
});
```

Note the `reducers` prop of `createSlice` API:

```
reducers: Object<string, ReducerFunction | ReducerAndPrepareObject>
```

If you want to use `say` in `reducers` it should be:

```
const say = (state, payload) => {
  console.log("saying", payload);
  state.currentList = payload;
};


const uiSlice = createSlice({
  name: "ui",
  initialState: { said: "" },
  reducers: { say }
});

// Usage
dispatch(uiSlice.actions.say(whatToSay));
```

[image: Edit redux-toolkit]

> [@markerikson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/62937/markerikson): with `createSlice`, the reducers field is for defining reducers and generating actions that will match those reducers. The `extraReducers` field is for handling actions that were already defined elsewhere.

Comment: I thought extraReducers was just for handling async actions (from the docs). Now I'm confused: Why are there 2 types and when should we use each of them? Also, how would reducers: { say } work since say is an action creator? How do we set the said state field?

Comment: For async actions you use `createAsyncThunk` API, `extraReducers` are for making reducers but that depends **on other actions** than in the slice, in this example putting `say` action there is useless. There are plenty example in the docs, can't explain better

Comment: You are asking good and a lot of question, so please just open new threads for it, I answered on the original question and we should focus on that.

Comment: Yes you are right, `{say}` should be from `createReducer`, my bad.

Comment: You said the "say" action shouldn't be in the extraReducers since it belongs to the uiSlice and I understand that. But the example you have in your answer is incorrect with reducers: {say}. Can you edit your answer and include the correct way? That is, using createAction and createSlice, how do we add the action to the slice?

Comment: I updated the answer, you can check the sandbox too.

Comment: To expand on this: with `createSlice`, the `reducers` field is for defining reducers and generating actions that will match those reducers.  The `extraReducers` field is for handling actions that were already defined elsewhere.

Comment: I think he's not: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createslice#reducers